# Не получается задать InReplyTo Mailkit c#

Tags: c#, .net, mailkit

Всем добрый день!
Пытаюсь в отвеченном сообщении задать заголовок InReplyTo  следующим кодом:

```
// construct the In-Reply-To and References headers
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (message.MessageId)) {
    reply.InReplyTo = message.MessageId;
    foreach (var id in message.References)
        reply.References.Add (id);
    reply.References.Add (message.MessageId);
}
```

но при отправке писем в gmail , письмо на которое мы отвечали так и остается одно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если я отвечаю на письмо, напрямую из gmail, то это все выглядит вот так, то есть они прям видно, что ссылаются друг на друга и смаплены. Как мне добиться такого же результата, при отправке из моего почтового клиента:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

разобрался, не хватало следующего  `reply.Subject = "Re: " + message.Subject;`